# Self-referencing connections in Relay?

Tags: relayjs

With Relay, I can create a connection to a GraphQL type, and then use that connection to define a field in some other type.

However, is it possible to create a connection, and use it in the same type? My underlying data source is a SQL table with a self-referencing key. There are no cycles in the data when represented as a graph. Can I model this relationship directly in GraphQL by creating a "self" connection, or is this the wrong approach? I couldn't find a way to do this without creating a circular module dependency in my code.

Would I do better to think of this data in a "flattened" manner and just abandon the idea of self-connecting? Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far? I believe this should be possible because you can pass a thunk in to [`connectionDefinitions`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/f1dfe502cfeccf80deadce3ce2cfde618a8acb36/src/connection/connection.js#L82) via `config.resolveNode` (assuming you are using the graphql-relay NPM package), which allows you to avoid the circular dependency (specifically if you do all of this within a single module).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out a solution which I posted below. How would this work with passing a thunk to config.resolveNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a self-referencing connection with code like the following (using graphql 0.6.0 and graphql-relay 0.4.2:

```
import { GraphQLObjectType } from 'graphql';

import {
  connectionArgs,
  connectionDefinitions,
  connectionFromArray,
  globalIdField,
} from 'graphql-relay';

import { nodeInterface } from './nodeDefinitions';
import { getRelatedData } from './dataSource';

const dataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Data',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Data'),
    related: {
      type: connectionDefinitions({
        name: 'Data',
        nodeType: dataType,
      }).connectionType,
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (parent, args) => connectionFromArray(
        getRelatedData(parent.id),
        args
      ),
    },
  }),
  interfaces: () => [nodeInterface],
});
```